# Не перемещается куб Blender 2.82

Tags: blender

Раньше работал с blender 2.79, все было понятно и просто. Сейчас вот обновился, выбираю объект, выбираю инструмент "Move" (через клавишу G тож самое), тяну за стрелку, иии... Ничего, двигается только его силуэт. Как быть?

PS: Еще на стоковом кубе почему-то нет теней.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот баг репорт с вашей проблемой: https://developer.blender.org/T73854

И ответ на него:

> Thanks for the report. This GPU is below the minimum requirements for
>   Blender, so we no longer provide support for it.
>   https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/
>
> Installing the latest graphics driver sometimes helps to make such
>   GPUs work, see here for more information.
>   https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/gpu/index.html
>
> If that doesn't help, you can use Blender 2.80 if it didn’t have this
>   issue: https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/

Попробуйте обновить драйвера видеокарты, если это не поможет, придется заменить видеокарту на поддерживающую OpenGL 3.3

Comment: Это мне не помогло но я еще поискал и наткнулся на то что Blender 2.8 не поддерживает видеокарты AMD с архитектурой terascale, я поставил на Blender интегрированную видеокарту intel и заработало.